# want to make jquery perform multiple actions or is there another way

Tags: php, jquery, html

Building off a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063625/how-to-show-hidden-data-types-in-php-loop) question,

Is it possible to make a jquery button do two things at once? 
Right now I have this:

```
<td>
 <a href="#'.$row['abstractid'].'">
   <button onClick="$(\'.hide\').toggle();">Read Abstract
   </button>
 </a>
</td>
```

This works (yay!) - it both jumps to and displays the div that is hidden with that database id number- but since those results are looped, it displays ALL of them. Now, it goes to the correct place on the page, but it still shows all the results instead of just that one result.

Could I make this button so onClick it not only toggles the hide **but also** sets the database ID number for the query to pull so it only displays one set of results- OR just only displays that one database ID set and leaves the others hidden? Would I have to set the table id as the database id and give that the class of hidden instead of putting it into a div?

Example: 
right now it's:

```
<div id="'.$row['abstractid'].'" style="display:none;" class="hide">
<table>
stuff
</table>
```

But would I need to make it

```
<table id="'.$row['abstractid'].'" style="display:none;" class="hide">
```

instead? This makes sense to me in theory but I'd have to be a little creative with my CSS I think.

Comment: Yes, jQuery can do what you're trying to do; just make sure your procedure is ordered properly. Write it down on paper, or in comments, in a step-by-step fashion until it makes good sense, then code it and fine-tune the code.

Answer (score 2):

You could use  `onclick="function() {$(\'.hide\').toggle();$(\'.hide\').toggle();}"`

However, I would not recommend that. My suggestion is:

`<button class="read-abstract">Read Abstract</button>`

Then

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".read-abstract").live( "click", function() {
        // do stuff here
    });
}
</script>
```

For more on unobtrusive Javascript: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Regarding showing and hiding values I always approach it as so:

HTML:

```
<button data-hide-id="1" class="read-abstract">Read Abstract</button>
<table id="table-1" class="hide">
    <tr>
        <td>Contents will show hide on click of read abstract</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS (in `<head>`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".read-abstract").live( "click", function() {
        $("#table-" + $(this).data("hide-id") ).toggle();
    });
}
</script>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/sZREt/

Comment: @bpeterson76 I'd love to take out inline attributes, but for tabular data when I put the attributes else where (into css or in a script) instead of in the table/tr/td lines, they never actually show up on the page....

Comment: You'd have to show us exactly what you're talking about, but there's ALWAYS a way to get an element in the dom.  It's just a matter of knowing the correct selector to use.  If I'm understanding you correctly, you could select it with a class, or select by table > row index > button for example.

Answer (score 0):

1. You toggle all items with the class "hide" instead of only the specific one
2. You don't need to put a button into an anchor (I don't even know if it's allowed). If you need it to look like a button you can use CSS.
3. IDs have to start with a letter and not with a number. I guess your `abstractid` is a number, therefore I prepended `abstr`
4. If you give an element the class `hide` (which presumably hides it) then you don't really need the inline style.

Here is the updated code:

```
<a href="#abstr'.$row['abstractid'].'" onclick="$(\'#abstr'.$row['abstractid'].'\').toggle()">Read Abstract</a>

<table id="abstr'.$row['abstractid'].'" class="hide">
```

Comment: Why does an ID need to start with a letter?

Comment: Rule #1 of Javascript, separate layers.  Inline onclick is bad general practice.

Comment: @the_red_baron It's in the HTML4 Specification http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id But I just found out that HTML5 doesn't have that restriction.